# How to create installer with inno setup with Port Checking

Tags: mysql, apache, port, inno-setup

I need to install a Web Application on client computer, I tried inno setup and succeed. But I want to add a form with 2 input and port checking for apache and mysql before installing the program. And change httpd.conf (apache) and my.ini (mysql) with desired port and install the service.
How to do that ?

Here my inno setup code

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "validasi"
#define MyAppVersion "1.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "ASDASDSDASD"
#define MyAppURL "http://www.ASDSADSAD.or.id/"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{0CE4DA97-8FE4-4BC8-97F0-7E2F91D61461}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
PrivilegesRequired=poweruser
DefaultDirName=C:\Program Files\Validasi
DisableDirPage=yes
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
OutputDir=D:\test installer
OutputBaseFilename=Validator
Compression=LZMA2/ultra64
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Files]
Source: "C:\Program Files\Validasi\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; Permissions: admins-full
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files 

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\VALIDASI"; Filename: "http://localhost:8177/validasi/";   
Name: "{commondesktop}\VALIDASI"; Filename: "http://localhost:8177/validasi//";
```

Comment: What should the "port checking" do?

Comment: to check if port is used, if it's used then use another port, the default port for apache is 8171 and mysql 8177, but who knows if some user are already use that port, so I need to add option to change port while installing